# Sorting SQL Query by Numbers as String

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on creating some reports from data that someone else created the databases for and am having trouble getting proper sorts.

This report is supposed to show the 20 most recent entries, but the data does not include a timestamp, instead it was created using two separate varchar fields, one for the date in the format `MM/dd/yyyy` and one for the time in the format `HH:mm:ss AM/PM`. This is causing issues when I try to select the most recent data.

When I use:

```
SELECT top 20 * FROM SignIn order by Checkin desc, Intime desc
```

I get the correct date, but the times are the values that start with 9:59am and go down from there alphabetically with 6am immediately after 7pm.

After doing much research I tried, among other things:

```
SELECT * FROM SignIn order by Checkout desc, CONVERT(varchar(30), outtime,  101) desc
```

The results were the same.

I don't do much in MS SQL, I am more fluent with with MySql and have never seen any reason to have dates stored as straight strings before. I am at a loss as to getting it to sort correctly.

I have tried creating the report with the html, php, and javascript handling the sort and display instead of having SQL just access the first records, but the load time is ridiculous since it loads the full 5000 pieces of data and then sorts them and clips all but the first 20.

As much as I wish I could, I can't change the database storage at this time, so I need something that will work with the varchars and handle the am\pm distinction if at all possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Given the formats involved, you'll need to manipulate *both* fields to get a proper chronological sort.  Since you'll need to do that anyway, why not compute proper `[small]datetime` values from the two fields, and then sort normally on that result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can concatenate the two columns and `cast` the result as `datetime` and use it for sorting.

```
SELECT top 20 * 
FROM SignIn 
ORDER BY cast(Checkout+' '+outtime as datetime) desc
```

Note that this assumes all the dates and times are valid. In case you may have incorrect values, use [`try_cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) (for SQL Server versions 2012 and later)

```
SELECT top 20 * 
FROM SignIn 
WHERE try_cast(Checkout+' '+outtime as datetime) is not null --invalid values get filtered out
ORDER BY cast(Checkout+' '+outtime as datetime) desc
```

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thank you for your quick responce!

Answer (score 1):

Just you have to concatenate your date time columns and convert to date like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM SignIn order by CONVERT(DATETIME, [dateColumn] + ' ' + [TimeColumn], 101) desc
```

you can learn more about datetime format in this tutorials [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)